# Magento - Remove inline CSS

Tags: css, magento

I'm trying to remove inline css that a previous developer added on category boxes.

He added a "min-height: 400px" to the product boxes on category pages.

```
<div class="product-item" style="min-height: 400px;">
```

Product boxes:

[Product boxes inside category grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvhjH.jpg)

Console inspector for the product box:

[Console Inspector Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te86Y.jpg)

I've visited list.phtml in          /app/design/frontend/.../template/catalog/product/list.phtml  and I can see the html that echos the div, but there is no "min-height: 400px;" inline css there.

How do I remove the inline "min-height: 400px" css?

I can't locate where it's coming from. Is there another .phtml file where this code is located?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems the `min-height` may be come from javascript as the developer want to keep equalheight for the .product-item div. thats why you can't see it in template. Debug your script for such codes .

**DO THIS AS LAST RESORT** Try overriding with `!important`.You can remove any value to `min-height` by giving `auto` as its value.

```
.product-item{ min-height: auto!important;}
```

This code can save you !!

Comment: It's bad practice to throw !important tags around.  This is highly discouraged

Comment: I couldn't find where the css is coming, but this ended up being a short-term fix. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user3896550 Apreciate it. But always keep in mind not to use !important tag too much as its not a best practice as mentioned by evan.

Answer (score -1):

List.phtml is broken into two pieces with a giant if, looking for grid or list view. It's possible that you overlooked it in list.phtml.

If that doesn't turn anything up, enable template hints. That will give you the exact path to the template responsible.